# Justifying text in HTML email for outlook

Tags: html, outlook, alignment

I've been struggling a little with creating an HTML email that will work properly in Outlook 2007. The email structure is based on HTML tables, and this has allowed me to fix most issues. However, for some reason `<p align="justify>` will not work in the table cells.

Is there a work-around or am I doomed to create messy text in emails?

Comment: Have you tried to justify your text from another tag than P? Like on a table-cell? Could there be 'floats' that interfere with your layout?

Answer (score 7):

Use CSS instead:

```
<p style="text-align: justify">
```